# New to C++ and wondering what getline() and cin are doing in my code

Tags: c++, stream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

void computeFeatures( string );

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
string name;

cout<< "Please enter your full name" << endl;

cin >> name;

cout << "Welcome" << name << endl;

cout << "Please re-enter your full name: ";

getline(cin, name);

cout << "Thanks, " << name << endl;

return 0;
}
```

The output is this:

```
Please enter your full name
John Smith
WelcomeJohn
Please re-enter your full name: Thanks,  Smith
```

I guess my question is why does cin print out the first name and why does getline() print the second name. Is there a way to print both?

Comment: `cin >> name` reads a word; `getline(cin, name);` reads a line.

Comment: but why does getline only read the second half of the line (Smith) and not the whole thing?

Comment: Because the first half was already read by `operator>>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cin` takes the first word as it's input and the second one which is separated by space is waiting in input buffer. Thus the `getline()` gets the last name automatically and doesn't even wait for any user input.

You should only use `getline(cin,name)` if you want both first and last name in string variable name.

Comment: is it possible to have two strings in an input buffer or does the second automatically replace the first.

Comment: the value of name is replaced. If you used a different variable in getline then name would retain first name in it.

Answer (score 1):

When you read input with [`cin >> name`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%3E%3E/) the input stops at the first space (blank, tab, newline).  So it reads only "John".

When you then call [`getline()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/) it continues where it stopped, starting at "Smith" and reading until the end of this line.

If you want to start reading  with `>>` but then skip the rest of the input until the next line, you can use:  [`cin.ignore(SIZE_MAX, '\n');`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)

Comment: so how would i print the whole line?

Comment: @Joesalad I've added an explanation how to skip input until the end of the line.

Answer (score 1):

cin only reads the first word, getline reads until it gets an /n. So if you want to print both you should do this:

```
cout<< "Please enter your full name" << endl;

getline(name);

cout << "Welcome" << name << endl;

cout << "Please re-enter your full name: ";

getline(name);

cout << "Thanks, " << name << endl;
```

Also, when you say getline(cin, name) you first read the first name with and then the rest of the input with getline and you only put the last name in 'name'because you already read the first name with cin, but didn't place this in 'name'.

Comment: but i did place the cin in name when i did cin >> name;

Comment: Yes you did, but wen you did getline (cin,  name) you didnt.  You Just read the first name with cin, cin does not 'remember' any value. It Just reads it. With cin >> name you put what cin reads in name. But then you overwrite name with getline (cin, name).